# Passing a param to a scope definition Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, parameters, scope

I am trying to write a generic sorting library for my application and am running into some problems.  I have a scope definition within my `class WorkOrder` that looks like this:

```
scope :join, lambda {|join_model, sort_direction, sort_by| {:joins => join_model, :order => sort_by + " " + sort_direction}}
```

The `join_model`is passed as a param to the controller who asks the model for a sorted list based on the passed in params. Simple enough...

```
@work_orders = @order.work_orders.join_to({:product_configuration => :product}, "ASC", "item").all
```

This works very well as WorkOrders `belongs_to :product_configuration` and ProductConfigurations `belongs_to :product`.

But if I want to call it like so:

```
work_orders = @order.work_orders.join_to("worker", "ASC", "item").all
```

or

```
work_orders = @order.work_orders.join_to(:worker, "ASC", "item").all
```

I get an error. I am sure you want to know that WorkOrders `belongs_to :worker`

So to sum it all up, when I try to go to `http://localhost:3000/foo?direction=ASC&join_to=worker&sort=name` I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in FooController#index
PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "work_orders"
LINE 1: SELECT "work_orders".* FROM "work_orders" worker WHERE (work...
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, as I'm rather new to Ruby and Rails.

**Update**

If I change my scope definition to 
`scope :join, lambda {|join_model, sort_direction, sort_by| {:joins => join_model.to_sym, :order => sort_by + " " + sort_direction}}`

I do not get an error message when I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/foo?direction=ASC&join_to=worker&sort=name` but I do when I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/pretzel?direction=ASC&join_to%5Bproduct_configuration%5D=product&sort=item`

The error message is

```
undefined method `to_sym' for {"product_configuration"=>"product"}:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
```

Comment: The table names are prularized, have you tried using it with `workers`?

Comment: Thanks @Matzi! But this does not work as this is not a SQL command, rather a rails scope definition.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Also, can you post your model code that declares the `belongs_to` relationship between `Worker` and `WorkOrder`?

Comment: @Brandan
Rails 3.2.3
ruby-1.9.3
'class WorkOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :worker'
'class Worker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :work_orders'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rewriting this scope as a class method, and use the methods from `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods` instead of the older hash-style syntax. I was able to get something similar to this working in a dummy application.

```
def self.join_to(join_model, sort_column, sort_direction = 'ASC')
  joins(join_model).order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
end
```

Comment: How should I pass in the join_model? Like '{:product_configuration => :product}'?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue. There was no need to Join `WorkOrders` and `Workers`. I just pass in `nil` for columns that do need a join to be sorted.

```
  def self.join_to(join_model, sort_direction = 'ASC', sort_column)
    if join_model == 'nil'
      order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
    else
      joins(join_model).order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
    end
  end
```

and I just pass `worker_id` as the `sort_column`

Thanks,
Shawn